# starting an app using adb command error type 3

Tags: android, adb

I have the following command

```
 adb -s 077743323A102985 shell am start -n com.instagram.android/.MainActivity
```

i am trying to start the instagram app via command line, but why does it gives me this error:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.instagram.android/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.instagram.android/com.instagram.android.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

the app is installed and the package name is com.instagram.android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `LauncherActivity` instead of `MainActivity`. The package name of the LauncherActivity is also a little bit different.

To sum up, the following command will start Instagram app from the terminal:

```
adb -s 077743323A102985 shell am start -n com.instagram.android/com.instagram.mainactivity.LauncherActivity
```

In order to know which Activity to use to start an app you can follow these steps:

1. get the apk of the app
2. extract the `AndroidManifest.xml` file
3. search for `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` and `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>` intent filters
4. get the activity by looking at the `android:targetActivity` attribute

You can apply these steps to all apps not only Instagram.